# __getitem__ returning inherited dataframe accessor impeding arithmetic operator overloading

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After addition of a *getitem*_ my implementation of "+" df-arithmetic operator overloading no longer works.. Would would anyone have a suggestion on resolution ?

```
class df(pd.DataFrame)
...
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return super(df,self).iloc.__getitem__(key)
...

...
    def __add__(self,o)
        return (self).add(o).combine_first(self)

def main():
    num_rows_1=8
    dates_1 = pd.date_range('2000-01-01',periods=num_rows_1)
    df_1=df(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(num_rows_1,4),index=dates_1,columns=['A','B','C','D'])

    num_rows_2=3
    dates_2 = pd.date_range('2000-01-03',periods=num_rows_2)
    df_2=df(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(num_rows_2,4),index=dates_2,columns=['A','B','C','D'])

    print (df_1 + df_2)

if __name__='__main__':
    main()
```

if **getitem** section is commented out, it works, but if included, runtime returns:
"TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key"

There seems to be a conflict with the + op-overload code versus the getitem code.. Is there a way round this ? (Apologies for any typo's in snippet)

Thanks in advance for any feedback..

Stack trace:
df_result = df_1 +df_2
..
return (self).add(o).combine_first(self)
..
return self.combine(other,combiner,overwrite=False)
..
series=this[col]
..
return super(df,self).iloc.**getitem**(key)
..
return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable,axis=axis)
..
File "...\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2129, in _getitem_axis
raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")

Comment: I'd assume because *something* in `.add` or `.combine_first` uses `__getitem__` but you changed the signature (which really goes against LSP). Maybe just don't do that and use `iloc` the way the entire API is designed?

Comment: Importantly, **if you are getting an error then provide the full error message including the stack trace**